# Asp.net Asynchronous programming model and Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

I am a bit confused here with the way in which asynchronous programming can be done.
As I think, I can always use AJAX for the same.

Answer (score 1):

> I am a bit confused here with the way in which asynchronous programming can be done.

I would recommend you the [following article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) if you want to do real asynchronous programming on the server. AJAX concerns only the client side part (javascript). You could still have perfectly synchronous server code but by using AJAX you are *faking* from the client perspective an asynchronous call so that his browser stays responsive and is able to perform other tasks on the page during the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AJAX is used most of time and it will handle Asynchronous request, but you can use [jquery](http://www.google.com.pk/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=XdAiTriWCJDusgb2p-WvAg&ved=0CBQQBSgA&q=getting+started+with+jquery+asynchronous&spell=1&fp=97340d1897d20133&biw=1366&bih=667) as well for your Asynchrous operation as well.

Comment: I know what u say, But whats the use of this approach http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asynctransactionhandler.aspx